# putting p or div before H1 in section

Tags: html, semantics, semantic-markup

I am wondering if it's ok to put p/div before h1 inside section?

example:

```
<section>
   <div class="breadcrumbs">Home | Bla | Bla </div>
   <h1>Heading</h1>
   <p>content</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4):

yes it is. The question might be if you want it SEO-wise. The higher up the more important, and we are guessing that your h1 is also really important (content wise).

But if it's really as small as you show here, no trouble at all

Comment: yes, I was wondering about the SEO-wise. Thank you, Nanne!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's perfectly OK to do this, there's no reason an `H1` has to be the first thing on a page, as long as it's an H1 (or other heading) it will maintain the same importance for those browsers or SE's that outline documents  - IOW it will maintain it's semantics as the heading